# delete field in nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to delete a field "_types" which is an array in all documents, including other nested documents in a collection. I researched and found several articles suggesting solutions and I've tried them all. The all result in matches but no modification ("nMatched": 1, nModified: 0).

example document:

```
{
  _cls: foo,
  data_servers: [
    {
      name: bar,
      _types: [baz, qux]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the array called _types, I don't care what's inside it, just want the field gone. suppose it's in a collection called test.

I've tried:

`* db.test.update({}, {$unset: {"_types":1}}, multi=true)`
`* db.test.update({}, {$unset: {"data_servers._types": ""}})`
`* db.test.update({}, {$unset: {"data_servers.$._types: ""}})`

And all of these result in matches but no modifications:

`WriteResult{{"nMatched": 1, "nUpserted": 1, "nModified": 1})`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
db.test.update( 
 {}, 
 {$unset:{"data_servers._types":1}}, 
 false,true 
)
```

Maybe the issue with your code is if you are passing options to update it should be a object

```
db.test.update(
 {},
 {$unset:{"data_servers._types":1}},
 {multi:true}
)

References [Update][1] and [$unset][2]


  [1]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update
  [2]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/
```